# PHP- Store multiple images or display in different sizes?

Tags: php, image, web

I am storing all the images in a folder. These images are uploaded by the user through his account. Hence, the images are of different sizes.

I want to display the images in 2 div elements with a fixed width and height (but different from each other) . The sizes may be of the order 40*40 pixels and 200*200 pixels. What would be the better way to do it -
1) Storing images of different sizes in the folder while uploading at the first place, or

2) Using the 'height' and 'width' attributes in img tag in HTML to display the image in the correct size.
Or is there some other way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The better way is storing the images in different size to optimization  request HTTP. Another good way is store only the original size and when the client request the image, proccess live and return the appropiate image (As Youtube made: https://yt3.ggpht.com/-RPO5pe1kzoU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/oTpb6gCTRXY/s125-c-k-no/photo.jpg). (sorry for my english :s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's better to store images already resized and cropped.
If you want to have multiple images with different dimensions .
It will send less data across.

The better way is too store all sizes of all images.In that case it works much faster.

> ```
> original/test.jpg
> 40x40/test.jpg
> 200x200/test.jpg
> ```

Also please read this article 
http://selbie.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/scale-crop-and-center-an-image-with-correct-aspect-ratio-in-html-and-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to store the original image and request the correct sized image from the client.  At that time if the correct size image is not found, create it and add it to a cache folder.  Then, deliver the correct size image from the cache.

So if image.png of size 1200x800 is uploaded, store that in original_images folder.

Then, construct a php script sized_image.php and use it in your HTML like this

```
<img src="sized_image.php?img=image.png&height=200&width=200" />
```

In your sized_image.php script you would do the following

```
$fileName = "cached_image/{$_GET['width']}x{$_GET['height']}_{$_GET['img']}";
if (!file_exists($fileName))
{
    //resize and store in $fileName
}


$type = 'image/png'; //Or whatever type the image is
header('Content-Type:' . $type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
readfile($fileName);
exit();
```

Comment: nice ideea but resize function is time consuming, at least i tried with imagemagick and it tooked a long time, can you tell me a better solution.

Comment: @RotariRadu It would only execute the resize once, for each additional request after that it should return the already sized image from the cache.

Comment: @RotariRadu There are plenty of efficient PHP resize scripts out there, use any one of those and the effect will be negligible.